# Blazor MSAL AD B2C integrate multiple user flows (profile edit, change email, change phone number)

Tags: azure, blazor, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have an AD B2C tenant with the user flows `SignupSignin, ProfileEdit, ChangeEmail, ChangePassword` userflows. I am trying to integrate the user flows in the Blazor application.

The Blazor client application has the appsettings.json file has option to specify only one user flow

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Authority": "https://tenant.b2clogin.com/tenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signupsignin",
    "ClientId": "*************",
    "ValidateAuthority": true
  }
}
```

Is there any way to call the other user flows from the Blazor application `ProfileEdit, ChangeEmail, ChangePassword`?

Is there any way to change the Authority dynamically at runtime on clicking the menu profile edit, change email and change password to navigate to the b2c userflows?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about changing Authority at run-time, but ...

here is something I managed to get working for an **Edit Profile** policy implementation in my Blazor Server application connecting to Azure AD B2C. It did take many hours of trial and error but please see my code and references below.

Appsettings.json

```
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://********.b2clogin.com/",
    "ClientId": "********************",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Domain": "***********.onmicrosoft.com",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_SignupSignin",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignupSignin",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_PasswordReset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_EditProfile"
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, Microsoft.Identity.Web.Constants.AzureAdB2C);

    services.AddControllersWithViews()
     .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
...
}
```

Then I created a `LoginDisplay` component, which is used in the MainLayout page.

```
@using Microsoft.Identity.Web
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Options
@inject IOptionsMonitor<MicrosoftIdentityOptions> microsoftIdentityOptions

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        @if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/EditProfile">Hello @userName</a>
        }
        else
        {
            <text>Hello there!</text>
        }
        <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignOut">Log out</a>
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <a href="MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn">Log in</a>
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>

@code {

    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    private bool isAuthenticated;

    private string userName;

    private async Task GetUsername()
    {
        var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var user = authState.User;
        isAuthenticated = user.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        if (isAuthenticated)
        {
            userName = user.FindFirst(x => x.Type.Contains("givenname")).Value;
        }
    }

    protected override async void OnInitialized()
    {
        await GetUsername();
    }
}
```

I used the official MS documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C) code sample.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, did this answer help at all?